# Resolving contact groups in Outlook C#

Tags: c#, outlook

I have a method that follows like this,

```
string email = "Group 1";
mail.Recipients.Add(email);
mail.Recipients.ResolveAll();
```

Group 1 is a contact group in the addressbook that contains an number of emails.

If I paste Group 1 into the recipient bar of outlook itself and click check names, it resolves just fine.

If I run the code,

```
string email = "Bob";
mail.Recipients.Add(email);
mail.Recipients.ResolveAll();
```

It resolves just fine, so it works for indaviduals, it seems to be unable to resolve groups though.

Do groups need to be treated in a diffrent way?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the similar forum thread which describes issue - [Error sending email to a distribution list via vba](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/ee9ba6e1-b2c6-43fa-85bc-9e6f5058ddb3/error-sending-email-to-a-distribution-list-via-vba?forum=ITCG).

It states that Clearing Auto complete solve the problem. Looks like a bug.